# ```An error occurred while calling o62.sql. : java.lang.ClassCastException: ``` exception when upgraded to spark 3.5.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We had recently upgraded to spark 3.5.0 and those spark scripts that were working before started throwing the following exception

```
An error occurred while calling o62.sql.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileStatusWithMetadata (org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus and org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileStatusWithMetadata are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

exact same query works fine when I run it from pyspark shell. But when I put the same in a python script (using pyspark==3.5.0 from pip) I get the above mentioned error.